# is it possible to split network connection among applications?

Tags: internet, connection, process

For instance if I am connected to 2 networks (using XP)

then, I launch 2 browsers:
 chrome and Fire-Fox.

can chrome be bind to connection 1 et fire-fox to connection 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you use a proxy.  Have one browser go to the proxy, and that proxy forward to one of the connections.  The other browser go to the default gateway the computer will go to which would be out the other connection.  There are probably many free proxy programs you can run in the system tray so you can turn that on and off.

Also, you could setup a VM with a proxy app to act as a proxy, or run the other browsers in the VM and have the VM go though the other connection.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not, it's not possible.

OSI model. You don't route apps but protocols.

Comment: In deed. Please consider to upvote ;)

Comment: need 15 in rep to upvote dude ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using different network cards, it might be possible:  http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2010/03/22/bind-windows-application-to-specific-network-adapter-with-forcebindip/

Answer (score 0):

Since both browsers use the same protocol(s), they'll both use the same connection.  But see [How to Bind & Unbind Network Protocols](http://www.ehow.com/how_5329024_bind-unbind-network-protocols.html) for binding protocols to different connections.  I don't know whether this allows, f/ex, to bind http: to one connection and https: to another, but that might be a way to assign browsers to connections.  One could easily imagine doing this to assign FTP: and http: f/ex, to different connections.